# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined. NodeJS. Instagram Api

Tags: node.js, undefined

[JSON Object structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXaN7.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu9p0.png)

I have very difficult to resolve error. I dont know why i cant reach my value. It parsing right. I am working on nodeJs and thats my code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            if (tag.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges[i].node === undefined) {
                continue;
            }
            let $this2 = tag.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges[i].node;
            let url = $this2.display_url;
            let id = $this2.id;
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Perharps node property does not exist in edge[i] object so try this:

```
if ( ! tag.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges[i].hasOwnProperty(node)) {
    continue;
}
```

this test check if node property exists